# How to sign someone into Google through HTTP

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-signin, google-account

I've been messing with Google OAuth2 and API's but it doesn't seem to achieve what I'm trying to do. I have a google form that I want to access but requires the user to login to their account before being able to access it. I thought the GoogleDriveAPI would work perfectly except for the fact that it only gets files that are in the USER'S drive, and not public files like the one I'm trying to access.(Assuming I'm reading the documentation right)

So what would be the best way to sign someone into Google through HTTP? The app I'm designing is a survey app and the idea is to send the user's response through HTTP to a google form. By requiring login, it will prevent multiple submissions from a single person. Is this a smart way of doing this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/). You need to enable Google+ API on [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). You can check the steps on this [tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-google-plus-integration-and-login-tutorial/).

You also need to configure Google Sign-In to integrate Google Sign-In into your Android app. For example, to configure Google Sign-In to request users' ID and basic profile information, you need to create a [`GoogleSignInOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#public-constructors) object with the `DEFAULT_SIGN_IN parameter`. To request users' email addresses as well, create the `GoogleSignInOptions` object with the `requestEmail` option.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```

Then, in your sign-in activity's `onCreate` method, create a `GoogleApiClient` object with access to the Google Sign-In API and the options you specified.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

Check this [example](https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo) on GitHub.

Comment: I am using Google Sign In, but it still gives me a 401 -unauthorized if I attempt to connect to the form. I've tried passing OAuth2 tokens for drive/google plus/forms APIs in a Authorization/Bearer request property (HttpUrlConnection) but that doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll get a 401 error if the authorization credentials provided for the request are invalid. Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header.